# Reading Value of an annotated field

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, annotations, java-8

I have a restful web service written in spring. the HTTP request are mapped on to a bean(I call it request object). I have custom annotation on each field in the bean.
My reqirement is to :
1. get all annotated field and check atleast value for one is provided.
And my problem is i dont know a way to READ VALUE of an annotated field. 
I wrote the below custom annotation

```
public class DocumentModifiedDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDocumentModifiedDate, String> {

    private String[] validDocumentModifiedDateValues;

    public void initialize(ValidDocumentModifiedDate constraintAnnotation) {
        //this.validDocumentModifiedDateValues = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

    boolean canProceed = false;
    for(Field field  : DocumentSearchRequest_global.class.getDeclaredFields())
    {

        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ValidDocumentModifiedDate.class))
            {
            String name = field.getName();
                System.out.println("1.name :   "+ name); //Iam able to get the name of the field
                System.out.println("2.            "+field.getType().getName());
                Class<?> targetType = field.getType();
                Object objectValue;
                try
                {
 //Idont know if i can use the below to read value of the field??? 
 //Please suggest a way so that 
  //so that i can read value of every element      
                    objectValue = targetType.newInstance();
                    Object value = field.get(new String());
                    System.out.println(value.toString());

                }
                catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }





            }
    }
        }
```

Comment: have a look at spring [validation](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) show us what you have tried?

Comment: i am not sure how can i get the values of all the field of my request object. I tried the following: for(Field field2  : ConstraintValidatorContext.class.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            Class type = field2.getType();
           
            if (field2.isAnnotationPresent(CheckOneValue.class))
                {
                String name = field2.getName();
                    System.out.println("1.name :   "+ name); 
                    System.out.println("2.            "+field2.getType().getName());
                    
                
                }

Comment: Have a look at [tutorial](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/versioned-validated-and-secured-rest-services-with-spring-40) and [this](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have updated to make it more clear... if u guys can help... all i need is a code sample to read value of an annotated field

Comment: All you need is to call `get` on the field, which your old code already did. Of course, in order to read the values of instance fields of `class DocumentSearchRequest_global` you will need an instance of `DocumentSearchRequest_global`. For reading `static` fields you can just pass `null`. The changes you made are nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spring Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) ,spring allows you to write customized validator and use annotation to reference your validators.